# срабатывание edittext

Tags: android, android-intent

у меня есть activity в котором есть edittext. когда я вхожу в этот activity сразу выскакивает клавиатура. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732761/how-to-avoid-automatically-appear-android-keyboard-when-activity-start

Answer (score 0):

в Manifest.xml, в активити укажи свойство

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Answer (score 0):

Укажи в корневом компоненте в зависимости от того что у тебя, или это LinearLayout или Relative добавь:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```